# Combining two SQL Update Statements in Access with VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have two update statements:

```
Dim newvalue As Integer
sSQL = "UPDATE Workstations SET SID = 0 WHERE SID = txtID3"
DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
```

AND

```
Dim strsql As String
strsql = "UPDATE Workstations SET [SID] = " & newvalue & " WHERE [Workstation ID] = '" & selectedwks & "'"
DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
```

When I run my code, it prompts me with two yes/no windows right after another saying whether if I want to update the table or not.

Is it possible to write those two update statements together so that I'm only prompted once? If yes, how should I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not see these two update statements as being compatible.  You are potentially (and quite likely) targeting two different rows (or sets of rows if SID and [Workstation ID] are not unique).

If you are are actually trying to target a row where the SID AND [WorkStation ID] are a match on what the user inputs, then just change your WHERE clause to include both columns separated by AND.  Else, I am not sure you can logically accomplish what you're asking.

Comment: They are targeting and updating different rows. Thing is I just want to do it so that it doesn't prompt me twice. Because right now, I can press yes for one and no for the second prompt. That results in a screwed up database :\

Comment: Use the `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` to bypass the prompts.  This will run both queries without user interaction.  Make sure to reset them though with `DoCmd.SetWarnings True`

Comment: I'm thinking of putting the     DoCmd.SetWarnings False after the first query. So that it still prompts. This works for if the user presses yes, but if the user presses no, then  the first query will not run, but the second will :\

Comment: If you don't want the prompts, I think Mike's answer is the correct one.  But you say you want one prompt, which leaves me a little confused about your goals.  I get the impression you're trying to gather user input and use it for two separate UPDATE queries, but perhaps I misunderstand your intentions.  If I'm correct though, perhaps you would best write some VBScript to prompt the user one time for the values you want to use in the updates, store the values in variables, use DoCmd.SetWarnings False as Mike suggests, and feed the UPDATE statements with the variables you filled earlier?